# Procedural studio scene during rendering

Tags: rendering, scene

I'm new to Blender.

I will have many different 3D models that I would like to render on the same scene, it should be a simple studio scene with lighting and a background.

I would like to know if it's possible to automatically create the scene, like lighting and background plane every time I render one of the 3D models, so I would not need to setup the scene for each 3D model.

I imagine something like a preset that when I render, it will create the scene on the fly and the elements like background plane are not saved along with the 3D model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not understanding the question, so I may not be able to answer it correctly.

It sounds like you are wanting Blender to automatically generate the studio scene for you whenever you render your 3d models.

My suggestion is that you build your scene in one Blender file and your models in another. Then you can Append your models to your scene and render them together. If this is not the answer you're looking for, please edit your post for clarification.

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to do. But I would like to avoid having to open a scene file and then put the object there as you said.

Comment: So you want the 3d models to be in the studio scene? Where does rendering the models separately come in?